# IOS iAd sample screenshot of test ads on device

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, iad

sorry to bother you guys with this most basic question.

so far I have managed to include the iAd feature into the apps - thanks to all you guys for the sample codes, my question is does anyone have a sample of screenshot of the "test ads" that were supposedly will be displayed on the devices during the testing period ? as accordance to the clause by [iAd app network webpage](https://developer.apple.com/support/appstore/iad-app-network/) :

*

> Once you've implemented iAd in your app, make sure to test ads by
>   running your app directly on an iOS device before submitting to the
>   App Store. **The iAd App Network can send "test ads" to help validate your
>   implementation and error handling**. If your app does not include the
>   proper delegate to handle errors, it will be rejected by the App
>   Review Team.*

so far i only see this images for the iAd on devices during test... no other:

[the "You're Connected to iAd" image](http://apps.starahead.com/iAd_available.jpg)

anyone have a sample images of "test ads" from the iAd network ? or is this the "test ads" ?

your most kind reply is greatly appreciated.

Thank you

best regards.

--

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the test ad. All things are working fine in your app. I don't have a screen shot to show you. But this is what I see all the time.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, the strange thing is my apps got rejected with comment: not hiding the "blank ads" with attachment screenshot of this "test ads"... and I have already got the function "didFailToReceiveAdWithError" in place to cater for ads failed to load... any idea what can I do to re-submit the apps for review ?

Comment: I would check to see if you are getting any errors.  One time while programming iAds, I had an error about unloading ads.  I didn't see the error in the console, but the ads loaded at first and seemed to work fine, but when I submitted, they did not work.  Also, in the didFailToReceive method, make sure you are hiding the ad so you don't get that blank space.  See my post on my blog http://thefizixgroup.blogspot.com/p/iad-implementation_6.html   Maybe this will help you out.

Comment: Thank you. will have a look.. is it in Swift ?

Comment: You are welcome.  It is not in swift, but Obj-C.  But you should be able to transform it pretty quickly.